# How to create new variable based on whether values in three columns are equal in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a large dataframe where three variables has the following structure:

```
author1_gender <- c("Men", "Men", "Women")
author2_gender <- c("Women", "Men", "Women")
author3_gender <- c("Men", "Men", "Women")

genders <- tibble(author1_gender, author2_gender, author3_gender)
```

which produces

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  author1_gender author2_gender author3_gender
  <chr>          <chr>          <chr>         
1 Men            Women          Men           
2 Men            Men            Men           
3 Women          Women          Women
```

I wish to create a new column based on whether there are mixed genders in the rows, i.e. if the three values in each row is equal or not. Ideally, I wish to add a column that indicates whether it is only female, only males or mixed genders in the three columns, i.e.,

```
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  author1_gender author2_gender author3_gender gender_mix
  <chr>          <chr>          <chr>          <chr>     
1 Men            Women          Men            mix       
2 Men            Men            Men            men       
3 Women          Women          Women          women
```

If I had two values, I could do this with `identital()`, however I can't seem to find out how to it with three values.  Can anyone help with this question which is probably quite trivial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could find the min and max for each row across columns whose names end with 'gender', then if the min equals the max return the max, else return 'mix'.

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
author1_gender <- c("Men", "Men", "Women")
author2_gender <- c("Women", "Men", "Women")
author3_gender <- c("Men", "Men", "Women")
genders <- tibble(author1_gender, author2_gender, author3_gender)

genders %>% 
  mutate(
    gender_mix =  
      lapply(c(pmax, pmin), do.call, across(ends_with('gender'))) %>% 
        {if_else(Reduce('==', .), .[[1]], 'mix')}
  )
#> # A tibble: 3 × 4
#>   author1_gender author2_gender author3_gender gender_mix
#>   <chr>          <chr>          <chr>          <chr>     
#> 1 Men            Women          Men            mix       
#> 2 Men            Men            Men            Men       
#> 3 Women          Women          Women          Women
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

If you have NAs you can add the `na.rm = TRUE` argument to `pmin` and `pmax`

```
genders %>% 
  mutate(
    gender_mix =  
      lapply(c(pmax, pmin), do.call, 
             c(across(ends_with('gender')),  na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
        {if_else(Reduce('==', .), .[[1]], 'mix')}
  )
```

Comment: Hi again! I have now tried with the full data - however, I have NA in my data, which I forgot to reflext in my reprex. I tried to accomodate this, however, I could not. Do you have an idea of how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

```
genders %>% mutate(gender_mix=ifelse(pmin(author1_gender, author2_gender, author3_gender)==pmax(author1_gender, author2_gender, author3_gender),author1_gender, "mix"))


# A tibble: 3 x 4
  author1_gender author2_gender author3_gender gender_mix
  <chr>          <chr>          <chr>          <chr>     
1 Men            Women          Men            MIX       
2 Men            Men            Men            Men       
3 Women          Women          Women          Women
```